# How can I upload multiple files in html form without selecting all at once?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi I am developing a website where it has form which should be able to submit multiple files. However the requirement is select files one by one so the multiple attribute in file input would not do. I tried to store the files in a array in javascript and then set it to a hidden input but that doesnt work as an array it goes as a object. Please let me know a work around for the problem. TIA.

The code I tried

javascript:

```
var selectedfiles;
  let filetosend=[];
  $('#file').change(function(){
    var file=this.files[0];
    selectedfiles=document.querySelector("#selectedFiles");
    selectedfiles.innerHTML +=file.name+'<br>';
    filetosend.push(file);
    var files=$('#allfiles').val();
    $('#allfiles').val(filetosend);
  });
```

html:

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <label>Documents:</label><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 upload-file-r">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" >
    <input type="hidden" id="allfiles" name="allfiles[]" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you just use the `multiple` attribute? This is a strange restriction

Comment: The user should be able to select the files one at a time rather than selecting all at once